# python module import error

Tags: python, module, dns, resolver

I am using macports to install various modules. Generally this works well, but below is an error I am getting that I am not easily resolving:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 12 2011, 16:57:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dns
>>> import opcode
>>> from dns import resolver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dns.message
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dns/message.py", line 28, in <module>
    import dns.opcode
ImportError: No module named opcode
```

Could this be a path issue?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info']
```

$ cat /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dns/**init**.py
    [snipped comments]
    # **init**.py for DNS class.

```
__version__ = '2.3.3'

import Type,Opcode,Status,Class
from Base import DnsRequest, DNSError
from Lib import DnsResult
from Base import *
from Lib import *
Error=DNSError
from lazy import *
Request = DnsRequest
Result = DnsResult
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `from dns import resolver` doesn't work? Can you post the content of `__init__.py` inside `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dns/`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you need to do:

```
from dns import resolver
```

This doesn't work:

```
import datetime.datetime
```

But this does:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

If you're importing a package that is part of another package, you need to use the "from" syntax

Comment: have you tried import dns, resolver = dns.resolver?  You've already got the dns package imported.

Comment: I have tried that now, and I still get an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'resolver'

Comment: I am able to import other modules from dns with no problem: tokenizer, reversename, ipv6, etc. Only resolver produces an error.

Comment: Ok. Found some other packages from dns that produce an error: update, win32dns, e164, (just noticed that the package Opcode is not lower case - wondering if that has something to do with it), message, haven't tested them all.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled py26-dnspython and reinstalled. Problem solved. Fink on freenode made the suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 3.7 and I installed pubdns. This resolved my problem. 
I faced extreme difficulty in using py3dns, pyDNS (won't install), dnspython and many more