# ImportError where path to module is in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, importerror, pythonpath

I'm not sure why I am still getting an `ImportError`

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_jabba.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tests import testbench
ImportError: No module named tests
```

Where error occurs:

```
from tests import testbench
from utils import gopher, jsonstream
```

I have this in my `.bashrc`

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/bli1/Development/QE/TrinityTestFramework/poc`

However, when I `echo $PYTHONPATH` nothing is returned

[image]

I added `__init__.py` within directories `tests` and `utils` as well but same error occurs

Comment: Ever solved this? I'm having similar issues (on Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `.bashrc` is correctly sourced?
If you run in your session

`echo $PYTHONPATH`

is it correctly set?
If not, try to manually export the path and then try to understand why your `.bashrc` is not being sourced. Possible trivial causes:

- You are using a shell different than bash, very trivial but might happen. Try to run `echo $SHELL`. Note that this might return `/bin/bash` even if you are not actually using bash. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281546/what-shell-am-i-in) post to find out which shell you are using. You can also start a new bash session manually (just run `/bin/bash`) and double check if `PYTHONPATH` is exported correctly there.
- You modified your `.bashrc` but you didn't start a new session.

Comment: Hmmm `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns nothing =/ I tried exiting all my terminal sessions and still getting empty python path

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` return?

Comment: when you edit you .bashrc, do you then call "source ~/.bashrc" or launch a new shell?

Comment: @nicolallias I launch a new shell because I thought bashrc automatically sources upon new shell instance

Comment: yes it does, you would have to use the "source" command if you wished to stay in the same shell.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the module and not the folder. The from something import something command only works for objects in the module file.  [Python module import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501473/python-module-import-error) or [python module import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206416/python-module-import-error) should help